# JSON in HTML with line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have some Javascript on my page that makes an ajax call which returns some JSON data.

With the result I do this:

```
results = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
console.log(results);
$('.box').append(results);
```

`.box` is just an empty div.

`console.log(results)` gives me an indented result with linebreaks but the data in `.box` is just all in one line.

How can I make sure that the result in `.box` is also on multiple lines and indented?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> .box is just an empty div.

Make it an empty [`<pre>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) instead:

```
<pre class="box"></pre>
```

Comment: The major problem about pre tag is that there is no scrollbar.

Comment: @cn123h Thats not true. Try setting the element's css with overflow: auto. Worked for me on latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with using `<pre>`, but another *option* is to replace all `\n` with `<br>` elements, and spaces with `&nbsp;`. It's probably really unnecessary (since `<pre>` preserves the whitespace). You can try:

```
var data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: {key4: "value4"}},
    results = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2),
    results2 = results.replace(/\n/g, "<br>").replace(/[ ]/g, "&nbsp;");
console.log(results);
$(".box").append(results2);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yk5Pb/3/